# Why there's no Int Index for Set struct in Swift?

Tags: swift, indexing, swift5

I know that Strings in Swift don't have `Int` indices as Swift supports Grapheme Clusters. But, when coming to Collections in Swift, `Array` supports `Int` indices but `Set` does not support `Int` indices. What is the reason behind this ?

Comment: Set is not ordered collection but Array is.

Comment: Think of a Set as a bag of objects all mixed up, whereas an array is a chain of objects all in a specific order.

Comment: But Set does allow to use Set.Index. How does it work ?

Comment: Note that Int indexes are the exception in Swift, not the rule. Most indexes are opaque types like Set. So it's not so much "why doesn't Set have an Int index," but "why does Array?" It isn't actually necessary for Array to have an Int index, and it is dangerous that it does. I opened a radar when Swift was brand new asking to remove it. The team felt it was too useful and too expected to do any other way. They were likely correct, but the point is that Array is unusual in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Set` has `Index` (a way to reference, iterate, etc. through members of the collection). But unlike `Array`, it makes no sense (and offers no utility) for this to be an `Int`. In an array, a numeric index offers utility for quickly accessing the memory associated for the object at that index. But `Set` uses hash tables for efficiently identifying items in the collection, not some integer-based offset.

In practice, when using sets, we generally add or remove items from a set and test membership, but we do not generally use indices as they are opaque and generally are not very meaningful or useful for the application developer.

It is a little dense, but the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Set.swift) for `Set` is available online. It is complicated a bit because it offers both native “set” implementation, but also bridging to `NSSet`. But any questions you have ultimately rest in the implementation.